# Get Correct Output : NSXML Parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My XML file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <count count="3" />
    <spac>
        <opt>aa</opt>
        <opt>bb</opt>
    </spac>
</plist>
```

I have used the following line of code for NSXML parssr :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"spaces"]) {
    //Initialize the array.
    appDelegate.api = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 
[appDelegate.api addObject:string];
    NSLog(@"the count is :%d", [appDelegate.api count]);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"spaces"])
    return;
}
```

But I am getting the following output at gdb and I'm unable to figure out the reason :

```
2012-06-05 02:20:57.940 XML[490:f803] the count is :0
2012-06-05 02:20:57.942 XML[490:f803] the count is :0
2012-06-05 02:20:57.943 XML[490:f803] the count is :1
2012-06-05 02:20:57.944 XML[490:f803] the count is :2
2012-06-05 02:20:57.945 XML[490:f803] the count is :3
2012-06-05 02:20:57.946 XML[490:f803] the count is :4
2012-06-05 02:20:57.946 XML[490:f803] the count is :5
2012-06-05 02:20:57.948 XML[490:f803] the count is :6
2012-06-05 02:20:57.948 XML[490:f803] the count is :7
2012-06-05 02:20:57.949 XML[490:f803] the count is :8
```

Can someone please help me out ?? I am new to objective C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you have two zeros printed out is because in your first callback you only create a new mutable array when the element is `spaces`.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"spaces"]) { //<- check for spaces to create array
    //Initialize the array.
    appDelegate.api = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
```

However, `- (void)parser:foundCharacters:` is called for each element that characters are found in. So the first nodes that are found get added to a nil array and print 0. Any node found after `spaces` will continue adding unwanted characters to it. If you had XML that looked like the following you can see what is happening.

```
<xml>
   <node1>text that is found but gets added to a nil array (prints 0 count)</node1>
   <node2>more text that is found but gets added to a nil array (prints 0 count)</node2>
   <spaces>this is the spaces text that will get added to the array correctly</spaces>
   <node4>this text will be added to the non-nil array and appear to be spaces</node4>
</xml>
```